# Dynamic Programming: Maximizing

Tags: algorithm, optimization, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

At a career fair, I was asked the following tough question(not exactly as below, I stripped out the story and expressed the problem (more or less) formally).

> Given number `K`, and a finite list of pairs `L = < (a,b), (c,d),
>   (e,f) >` where each pair `p` consists of two numbers `n1` and `n2`.
>   Find the the list `R` where the sum of the `n1` values of all its
>   pairs is the greatest and the sum of all the `n2` values of its pairs
>   is less than or equal to `K`. In the list `R`, pairs can repeat.

So for example, if your `K` is 10 and you have the list of pairs `L` as `<(3,2) , (1,7), (4,6) >`, then the result would be `R = < (3,2), (3,2), (3,2), (3,2), (3,2) >` so that the sum of all `n1` values would be `3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 15` and sum of all the `n2` values would be `2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 10`. This would be correct solution as opposed to something like `<(3,2), (3,2), (4,6)>` (`n1` sum is 10; `n2` sum is 10) or like `<(1,7), (3,2)>` (`n1` sum is 4; n2 sum is 9) whose `n1` sums are not the maximum possible.

I described an approach where I would essentially enumerate all possible combinations of pairs whose n2 values would sum to number less than or equal to `K` and pick the combination with highest `n1` sum. Enumeration could be done by incrementally subtracting from `K`, each of `n2` values from pairs in the given list `L`.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the "unbounded knapsack problem". It's NP hard, so there's no (known) polynomial solution, but there's a known pseudo-polynomial time solution if the n2 and K are integers, which you can find here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Solving

The dynamic programming solution described above, is to compute, for each capacity k, 0<=k<=K, and for each prefix of the list `L`, the largest value of sum(n1) such that the sum(n2)<=k.

Answer (score 0):

The important insight, I believe, is to note that the critical factor is the *ratio* of the two numbers, not their difference.  `K` is your budget; `n2` is the cost of each item, and `n1` is its value.  You need to maximize the value within your given budget.

Sort the list descending by the `n1/n2` ratio.  Apply the canonical recursion program (see the generalized "making change" problems) to explore the solution space.  If it's easier, sort descending by n2 alone; that will make it match the implementation of the coin problem more closely, but at the cost of more search for the optimal solution.

Note that you can prune recursion two ways:

1. The remaining pairs have a ratio too low to exceed the current best solution.
2. The next pair evenly divides the remaining budget: with a ratio-sorted list, that *must* be the optimal solution.

Is that enough of a hint to get you unstuck?

Comment: Can you please elaborate about the "Apply the cannonical recursion program..." part ? So once I have the set of ratios of n1/n2, how would I apply recursion to that ?

Comment: What don't you understand about the recursion in the coin-change problems?